# Ruby webapplication, getting "wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made some changes in one of the controllers in our webapp. Essentially, the controller was sending out an email to the customer if the order was cancelled, and changed the status of the order in the database. This is how it originally the snippet looked like:

```
  elsif @ac == "mino"
    begin
      @wifi_order = WifiOrder.find(params["id"])
      ApplicationMailer.cancelled_mino(@wifi_order, WifiUser.find_by(email: @wifi_order.email), 10000).deliver_now
      @wifi_order = WifiOrder.find(params["id"])
      @wifi_order.order_status = "status_cancelled_pending_fees"
      @wifi_order.order_status_sub = "status_cancelled_force"
      @wifi_order.cancelled_at = DateTime.now
      @wifi_order.payment_next = nil 
      @wifi_order.confirm = nil 
      @wifi_order.save!
    rescue => e
      p e.message
      flash[:error] = e.message 
      return
    end
```

This is what I changed it for, because I wanted to send two different kinds of emails depending on the payment method set:

```
  elsif @ac == "mino"
    begin
      @wifi_order = WifiOrder.find(params["id"])
      if @wifi_order.pay_type = "card"
        ApplicationMailer.cancelled_mino(@wifi_order, WifiUser.find_by(email: @wifi_order.email), 10000).deliver_now
      else
        ApplicationMailer.cancelled_mino_paid(@wifi_order, WifiUser.find_by(email: @wifi_order.email), 10000).deliver_now 
      end
      @wifi_order = WifiOrder.find(params["id"])
      @wifi_order.order_status = "status_cancelled_pending_fees"
      @wifi_order.order_status_sub = "status_cancelled_force"
      @wifi_order.cancelled_at = DateTime.now
      @wifi_order.payment_next = nil 
      @wifi_order.confirm = nil 
      @wifi_order.save!
    rescue => e
      p e.message
      flash[:error] = e.message 
      return
    end
```

Ever since the changes, when I try to test it, I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please don't just edit the title if you seem your question answered. Instead, if one of the answers helped you to resolve your question, please [accept it and possibly vote on it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Apart from the exception, you may also want to check your `if` statement. You likely want to write `if @wifi_order.pay_type == "card"` instead (note the double equals). With your current code, you are assigning `"card"` to the `pay_type` which will likely mess things up! Also, this will always take you to the `if` branch, rather then the `else` as you don't actually perform the comparison you intend.

Answer (score 0):

### Why it is happening

The wrong number of arguments you are getting hints at the solution.

It details a method is expecting 2 arguments while you are sending 3.

```rb
def say_hello(first_name, last_name)
 puts "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end

say_hello("John", "Doe") # -> will work
say_hello("John", "Von", "Doe") # -> will raise wrong number of arguments error
```

### How to fix it

At first sight, it seems that the method you've added `cancelled_mino_paid` is the cause of the wrong number of arguments error.

You can fix it in one of two ways:

1. when defining the `cancelled_mino_paid` method, make sure it can receive 3 arguments
2. only send 2 arguments when calling the `cancelled_mino_paid` method

Comment: Ah, I was looking for the problem in the controller, but it is in fact in the application mailer, you are right. Thank you!!